# Como fazer um elemento voltar como estava depois de uma ação com o jquery

Tags: jquery

Eu tenho uma li e pelo css deixei ela como um quadrado e coloquei uma imagem no fundo com o css, quando meu usuário clicar essa imagem sai e entra um texto e quando ele clicar de novo a imagem volta, gostaria de saber como faço para que a li volte a ser como era no começo depois desse novo click. Obrigado

Comment: Que tipo de ação? É alterada a posição, valor, atributo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize o método [clone()](https://api.jquery.com/clone/), que cria uma cópia do elemento.

```
var elementoOriginal = $("#box").clone();

$("#btn-remover").click(function() {
    $("#box").css('background','yellow');
});


$("#btn-restaurar").click(function() {
   $("#box").remove();
   $("body").prepend(elementoOriginal);
});
```

Veja exemplo funcionando no [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j66jhjtd/).